SAC Story - Measure Value/Text
I have a SAC Story in which i want to display the measure "Availlable Quantity".
In Query CDS View i have defined it as query.axis: #ROWS.
When creating the story i see just the EndUserText label on the rows and next to it the values, but i do not understand why the value is not directly visible in the Measure Column.

How can i change this to see the values directly in the Measure Column?
Query View:
@AnalyticsDetails.query.axis: #ROWS
@EndUserText.label: 'Available Qty'
odProb.AvailableQty as AvailableQty,

Cube View:
@DefaultAggregation: #SUM
odProb.AvailableQty as AvailableQty,

Thx in advance!

Ok this was quick.
Just drag and drop the measure into the columm.
Sry.


